# How to pass prop and implement function for increase and decrease button in component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

**PLease help me with this my problem. I need your help**

I have to do the increase and decrease button to make the number change.
But I do not know how to change that function and show it on the screen.
This is my `CartItem` component, this will contain the increase and decrease button function with name `Quantity`

```
import React from "react"
import { Image, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "../CartItem/index.css"
import Quantity from "../Quantity/index"

const CartItem = ({ image, name, price, onDeleteCartItem }) => {

  handleClickDecrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.state.quantity - 1,
    });
  };

  handleClickIncrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1,
    });
  };


  return (
    <Row className="cart">
      <Col className="cart-image">
        <Image className="image" src={image} alt={name} />
      </Col>
      <Col className="cart-name" as="h4">{name}</Col>
      <Col className="cart-quantity">
        <Quantity onIncrease={this.handleClickIncrease} onDecrease={this.handleClickDecrease} />
      </Col>
      <Col className="cart-price" as="span">{price} VNĐ</Col>
      <Col className="cart-delete" as="span" onClick={onDeleteCartItem}>&#9747;</Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

CartItem.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  price: PropTypes.string,
  onDeleteCartItem: PropTypes.func,
};

CartItem.defaultProps = {
  image: "",
  name: "",
  price: "",
  onDeleteCartItem: () => { },
};

export default CartItem;
```

This is my `Quantity.js` file. Where I code UI for that and set prop

```
import React from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Button from "../Button/index"
import "../Quantity/index.css";

const Quantity = ({ quantity, onIncrease, onDecrease }) => {
  return (
    <Row className="quantity p-0">
      <Col className="quantity-item p-0">
        <Button size="btn-sm" btnText="&minus;" onClick={onDecrease}></Button>
      </Col>

      <Col className="quantity-item p-0 result" as="span">{quantity}</Col>

      <Col className="quantity-item p-0">
        <Button size="btn-sm" btnText="&#43;" onClick={onIncrease}></Button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

Quantity.propTypes = {
  quantity: PropTypes.number,
  onIncrease: PropTypes.func,
  onDecrease: PropTypes.func,
};

Quantity.defaultProps = {
  quantity: 1,
  onIncrease: () => { },
  onDecrease: () => { },
};

export default Quantity;
```

this is the UI for that

[image]

**I would like to change that number in my `CartItem.js` component**, how can I do that. I do not know and clear for this section.

**Could anyone help me, please? I really thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to set the state, based on the last state

instead of an object

```js
this.setState({ quantity: this.state.quantity - 1 });
```

pass a function, that will get the last state as first parameter.

```js
this.setState(({ quantity }) => ({ quantity: quantity - 1 }));
```

Comment: Did this help? @Kite

Answer (score 0):

You're passing nothing to the Quantity component.
Each CartItem component should keep track of its own quantity as state.. That way you pass it down along with a function to update it as props to the Quantity component. Clicking increase of the Quanty component should then update the state of the CartItem...which in turn should defender the Quantity component to reflect the state change.

Comment: I do not now what exactly I will do for this Item, can you help me, I already edit my code in CartItem.js